# Change renderSize UIElement without changing width|height renderProperty

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am implementing flexbox for UWP (extends Panel), everything works great but I have an issue implementing FlexGrow and FlexShrink properties, if the panels child FlexGrow attachedProperty is > 0 I would like to enlarge the childs size so it take the remaining space on the main axis. I have all the calculations, but if I change directly the width|height dependencyproperty, the child doesnt go back to its default size when I set flexGrow zero or unset the FlexGrow attached property, obiviously because I changed the width|height. So is there any way to change only the rendering size of a UI element without changing the width and height DependencyProperties.

example:
in this case width 100 is defined, but the child should render with the width of its parent. The childs rects is enlarged in the panels `MeasureOverride` method, but the content(rectangle) stays 100 width

```xml
<controls:FlexPanel Direction="Row">
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue"
           Width="100"
           Height="100"
           controls:FlexPanel.FlexGrow="1"
     />
</controls:FlexPanel>
```

hack to overcome this issue is using MinWidth, in this case everything works fine, the childs rect is updated and the content is enlarged

```xml
<controls:FlexPanel Direction="Row">
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue"
           MinWidth="100"
           Height="100"
           controls:FlexPanel.FlexGrow="1"
     />
</controls:FlexPanel>
```

So is there any way to override the rendering width|height of a panels child when width|height are set without overriding the with|height dependency properties?

Comment: Nope. Perhaps you want to create attached properties instead like `controls:FlexPanel.DesiredWidth` & `controls:FlexPanel.DesiredHeight` and use those in your markup instead when a child of FlexPanel. This will leave you free to programmatically change the physical rendering Height/Width and still have a reference to the intended values. Alternatively, you can programttically create VisualStateManagers and VisualStates and let them manage it.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake Thanks I already played with that idea, I wanted to make it work with width and height, so I let attached properties as last time solution. Anyway, thanks for the answer. So I will go width attached properties.